# find all combinations with non-overlapped regions

Tags: algorithm, intervals, interval-tree

Within a super-region S, there are k small subregions. The number k can be up to 200. There may be overlap between subregions. I have millions of regions S.

For each super-region, my goal is to find out all combinations in which there are 2 or more non-overlapped subregions.

Here is an example:

Super region: 1-100

Subregions: 1-8, 2-13, 9-18, 15-30, 20-35

Goal:

Combination1: 1-8, 9-18

Combination2: 1-8, 20-35

Combination3: 1-8, 9-18, 20-35

Combination4: 1-8, 15-30

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of subsets might be exponential (max 2^k), so there is nothing wrong to traverse all possible independent subsets with recursion. I've used linear search of the next possible interval, but it is worth to exploit binary search.

```
def nonovl(l, idx, right, ll):
    if idx == len(l):
        if ll:
            print(ll)
        return

    #find next non-overlapping interval without using l[idx]
    next = idx + 1  
    while next < len(l) and right >= l[next][0]:
        next += 1
    nonovl(l, next, right, ll)

    #find next non-overlapping interval after using l[idx]
    next = idx + 1
    right = l[idx][1]
    while next < len(l) and right >= l[next][0]:
        next += 1
    nonovl(l, next, right, ll + str(l[idx]))

l=[(1,8),(2,13),(9,18),(15,30),(20,35)]
l.sort()
nonovl(l, 0, -1, "")

(20, 35)
(15, 30)
(9, 18)
(9, 18)(20, 35)
(2, 13)
(2, 13)(20, 35)
(2, 13)(15, 30)
(1, 8)
(1, 8)(20, 35)
(1, 8)(15, 30)
(1, 8)(9, 18)
(1, 8)(9, 18)(20, 35)
```