# Find all possible combinations that overlap by end and start

Tags: python, list, sorting, recursion, dynamic-programming

In the post [find all combinations with non-overlapped regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176104/find-all-combinations-with-non-overlapped-regionsI) (code pasted below), the function is given a set of tuples and it recursively finds every possible collection of tuples with non-overlapping values. On the list of tuples `T = [(0.0, 2.0), (0.0, 4.0), (2.5, 4.5), (2.0, 5.75), (2.0, 4.0), (6.0, 7.25)]`, for example, we get

```
def nonovl(l, idx, right, ll):
    if idx == len(l):
        if ll:
            print(ll)
        return

    next = idx + 1  
    while next < len(l) and right >= l[next][0]:
        next += 1
    nonovl(l, next, right, ll)

    next = idx + 1
    right = l[idx][1]
    while next < len(l) and right >= l[next][0]:
        next += 1
    nonovl(l, next, right, ll + str(l[idx]))

>>> T = [(0.0, 2.0), (0.0, 4.0), (2.5, 4.5), (2.0, 5.75), (2.0, 4.0), (6.0, 7.25)]
>>> l.sort()
>>> nonovl(l, 0, -1, "")
(6.0, 7.25)
(2.5, 4.5)
(2.5, 4.5)(6.0, 7.25)
(2.0, 5.75)
(2.0, 5.75)(6.0, 7.25)
(2.0, 4.0)
(2.0, 4.0)(6.0, 7.25)
(0.0, 4.0)
(0.0, 4.0)(6.0, 7.25)
(0.0, 2.0)
(0.0, 2.0)(6.0, 7.25)
(0.0, 2.0)(2.5, 4.5)
(0.0, 2.0)(2.5, 4.5)(6.0, 7.25)
```

How might we modify the `nonovl()` function so that it *also* allows for combinations that overlap by the start and end values of two tuples? Running it on the same list, for example, we would *also* get:

```
(0.0, 2.0)(2.0, 4.0)(6.0, 7.25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `>=` to `>`. Right now, the code skips over the "next" tuple if the left index value of the "next" tuple is less than ***or equal to*** the right index value of the "current" tuple. It finds the first tuple that has a left index value that is strictly greater than the current tuple's right index value.

```
def nonovl(l, idx, right, ll):
    if idx == len(l):
        if ll:
            print(ll)
        return

    next = idx + 1  
    while next < len(l) and right > l[next][0]:
        next += 1
    nonovl(l, next, right, ll)

    next = idx + 1
    right = l[idx][1]
    while next < len(l) and right > l[next][0]:
        next += 1
    nonovl(l, next, right, ll + str(l[idx]))
```

**Output:**

```
(6.0, 7.25)
(2.5, 4.5)
(2.5, 4.5)(6.0, 7.25)
(2.0, 5.75)
(2.0, 5.75)(6.0, 7.25)
(2.0, 4.0)
(2.0, 4.0)(6.0, 7.25)
(0.0, 4.0)
(0.0, 4.0)(6.0, 7.25)
(0.0, 2.0)
(0.0, 2.0)(6.0, 7.25)
(0.0, 2.0)(2.5, 4.5)
(0.0, 2.0)(2.5, 4.5)(6.0, 7.25)
(0.0, 2.0)(2.0, 5.75)
(0.0, 2.0)(2.0, 5.75)(6.0, 7.25)
(0.0, 2.0)(2.0, 4.0)
(0.0, 2.0)(2.0, 4.0)(6.0, 7.25)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to change it further so that these outputs could made into a list of one or more tuples instead of printing in string format? With the above data, the result would be ```[[(6.0, 7.25)], [(2.5, 4.5)], [(2.5, 4.5), (6.0, 7.25)], ..., [(0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 4.0), (6.0, 7.25)]]```. I don't have much experience with recursion and I'm getting all sorts of errors when trying to append each step to a list.

Comment: My question in the comment above seemed a bit complicated, so I made it a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901396/modify-for-list-output-in-recursion

Comment: It's not too big of a change. What you can do is create an empty list outside and fill it in instead of printing. I'll elaborate more as an answer in your other page.