# Iterative Solution to End-Overlapping Indices

Tags: python, list, loops, recursion, iteration

I have a list that holds tuples that represent ranges of numbers. My goal is to return all (see the note below; really looking for the longest) possible subsets of this collection that overlap only by the second value in each tuple or not at all. The function I have been using is a recursive solution to this problem.

```
def get_all_end_overlapping_indices(lst, i, out):
    all_possibilities = []

    def _get_all_end_overlapping_indices_helper(list_in, i, out):
        r = -1
        if i == len(list_in):
            if out:
                if len(all_possibilities) == 0:
                    all_possibilities.append(out)
                else:                       
                    all_possibilities.append(out)

            return 

        n = i + 1

        while n < len(list_in) and r > list_in[n][0]:
            n += 1
        _get_all_end_overlapping_indices_helper(list_in, n, out)
        r = list_in[i][1]

        n = i + 1
        while n < len(list_in) and r > list_in[n][0]:
            n += 1
        _get_all_end_overlapping_indices_helper(list_in, n, out + [list_in[i]])

    _get_all_end_overlapping_indices_helper.count = 0
    lst.sort()
    _get_all_end_overlapping_indices_helper(list_in = lst, i = 0, out = [])
    
    return all_possibilities
```

We get the following result with `lst = [(0.0, 2.0), (0.0, 4.0), (2.5, 4.5), (2.0, 5.75), (2.0, 4.0), (6.0, 7.25), (4.0, 5.5)]`

```
[(6.0, 7.25)]
[(4.0, 5.5)]
[(4.0, 5.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(2.5, 4.5)]
[(2.5, 4.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(2.0, 5.75)]
[(2.0, 5.75), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(2.0, 4.0)]
[(2.0, 4.0), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(2.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.5)]
[(2.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 4.0)]
[(0.0, 4.0), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.5)]
[(0.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 2.0)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (4.0, 5.5)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (4.0, 5.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.5, 4.5)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.5, 4.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 5.75)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 5.75), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 4.0)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 4.0), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.5)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
```

As I will eventually be dealing with larger collections of tuples (and this runs quite slowly), I'd like to implement an iterative solution; unfortunately, I'm stumped. This snippet originally came from: [Find all possible combinations that overlap by end and start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887631/find-all-possible-combinations-that-overlap-by-end-and-start). Although it works, I find it tricky to decipher *how* it's working. Could anyone provide some tips on how you might construct an iterative solution to this problem?

**Note:** I'm actually looking to get only the longest outputs (see below). I can always filter out the shorter ones (i.e. the ones that sit inside the longest ones) later, but if it makes it easier, I can gladly do away with them.

```
[(0.0, 2.0), (4.0, 5.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.5, 4.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 5.75), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** My previous answer did not really answer the question, so here is a piece of code that really does it.

What we need to find is a Pareto optimal frontier of sequences of non overlapping tuples (Pareto optimal in the sense of inclusion).

- First, we need to find the 'source' tuples, meaning the tuples that can be at the start of a tuples sequence.

```
sources = {
    (a, b)
    for (a, b) in tup_lst
    if not any(d <= a for (c, d) in tup_lst)
}
```

- Similarly, we compute a set of 'sinks', meaning a set of tuples that have to be at the end of a tuple sequence (they cannot have a successor).

```
sinks = {
    (a, b)
    for (a, b) in tup_lst
    if not any(b <= c for (c, d) in tup_lst)
}
```

- Then, for each tuple `a, b`, we compute a `min_successor` value. It corresponds to the smallest `d` such that there exists a `c, d` with `b <= c`.

```
min_successor = {
    (a, b): min(d for c, d in tup_lst if c >= b)
    for (a, b) in set(tup_lst) - sinks
}
```

- We can then compute, for each tuple, the list of its 'successors'.

```
successors = {
    (a, b): [
        (c, d)
        for (c, d) in tup_lst
        if b <= c <= d and c < min_successor[(a, b)]
    ] for (a, b) in tup_lst
}
```

- Finally, we can retrieve the longest sequences of non overlapping tuples.

```
def print_path_rec(node, path):
    if node in sinks:
        print(path + [node])
    else:
        for successor in successors[node]:
            print_path_rec(successor, path + [node])
for source in sources:
    print_path_rec(source, [])
```

input: `[(0.0, 2.0), (0.0, 4.0), (2.5, 4.5), (2.0, 5.75), (2.0, 4.0), (6.0, 7.25), (4.0, 5.5)]`
output:

```
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.5, 4.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 5.75), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
[(0.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.5), (6.0, 7.25)]
```

I think that this problem is not solvable in polynomial time, simply because the size of the output might be exponential w.r.t the input size.   Nevertheless, it will run rather fast since it takes `O(n²)` to build the  4 dictionaries, and then each path is being outputted in linear time w.r.t its length.

**End of edit, old solution below**

We can solve this problem in polynomial time by reducing it to the problem of the longest path in a DAG (directed acyclic graph).

First, we need to model the problem as a DAG. Each tuple represents a vertex, and we build an edge from `(a,b)` to `(c, d)` if and only if `b <= c`.

What we can then see is that (1) the graph obtained is acyclic, by construction and (2) the longest path from a vertex to another in this graph will represent the longest sequence of overlapping tuples.

Luckily, the longest path problem, which is NP-hard in the general case, is not hard in a DAG. The problem is described in length in [this document](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/171/Syllabus/11-Graph/Docs/longest-path-in-dag.pdf) (page 4).
The overall complexity to find the longest overlapping sequence of tuples should then be: `O(n²)` to build the graph,  `O(n²)` to sort vertices, and `O(n²)` to find the longest path, so `O(n²)` in the worst case. This is way faster than the recursive approach you were going for, since we don't want to enumerate all combinations, but we want only the longest.

Below is a python 3 code that will compute the longest sequence of tuples. In the case I misunderstood the 'overlap' relation on tuples, it is easily modifiable in the `overlap_condition` function.

```
def overlap_condition(tup1, tup2):
    if tup1 == tup2:
        return False
    a, b = tup1
    c, d = tup2
    return b <= c


def adj_mat_from_tup_list(tup_lst):
    return [
        [
            1 if overlap_condition(tup_lst[i], tup_lst[j]) else 0
            for j in range(len(tup_lst))
        ] for i in range(len(tup_lst))

    ]


def topological_sort(adj_mat):
    sorted_v = []
    sinks = {
        i for i in range(len(adj_mat))
        if not any(adj_mat[j][i] == 1 for j in range(len(adj_mat)))
    }

    while sinks:
        v = sinks.pop()
        sorted_v += [v]
        for j in range(len(adj_mat)):
            if adj_mat[v][j] == 1:
                adj_mat[v][j] = 0
                if not any(adj_mat[w][j] for w in range(len(adj_mat))):
                    sinks.add(j)
    return sorted_v


def get_longest_path(adj_mat, sorted_v):
    dists = {v: 0 for v in range(len(adj_mat))}
    preds = {v: None for v in range(len(adj_mat))}
    for v in sorted_v:
        for u in range(len(adj_mat)):
            if adj_mat[u][v]:
                dists[v] = max(dists[v], dists[u] + 1)
                preds[v] = u

    current_v = {
        v for v in range(len(adj_mat))
        if dists[v] == max(dists.values())
    }.pop()
    result = [current_v]
    while preds[current_v] is not None:
        current_v = preds[current_v]
        result += [current_v]
    return result[::-1]


def get_all_end_overlap_tups(tup_lst):
    sorted_v = topological_sort(adj_mat_from_tup_list(tup_lst))
    adj_mat = adj_mat_from_tup_list(tup_lst)
    return [tup_lst[i] for i in get_longest_path(adj_mat, sorted_v)]


lst = [
    (0.0, 2.0), (0.0, 4.0), (2.5, 4.5), (2.0, 5.75),
    (2.0, 4.0), (6.0, 7.25), (4.0, 5.5)
]

print(get_all_end_overlap_tups(lst))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, @m.raynal! This is very helpful to me. Using this framework, is it possible to retrieve other paths in the DAG that don't overlap? In my post, you might see (at the bottom) that I'm hoping to retrieve all (longest) non-overlapping paths like [(0.0, 2.0), (2.5, 4.5), (6.0, 7.25)] and [(0.0, 2.0), (4.0, 5.5), (6.0, 7.25)].

Comment: Hi, yes using this framework, it is possible to find a pareto-optimal frontier of longest paths. But I've been thinking about your problem this morning and I came up with a simpler, nicer solution outside of this frame, I'll post it tonight.

Comment: @LukePoeppel you can have a look at the new solution, I guess this answer your problem this time :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your edited answer. This is exactly what I was looking for! :-)